# formatting AWS glue output to JSON OBJECT

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

This is the result I get from my pyspark job in AWS GLUE

```
{a:1,b:7}
{a:1,b:9}
{a:1,b:3}
```

but I need to write this data on s3 and send it to an API in JSON array
format

```
[
 {a:1,b:2}, 
 {a:1,b:7}, 
 {a:1,b:9}, 
 {a:1,b:3}
]
```

I tried converting my output to DataFrame and then applied
 `toJSON()` 
`results = mapped_dyF.toDF()`
`jsonResults = results.toJSON().collect()`

but now unable to write back the result on s3 with `'write_dynamic_frame.from_options'`
as it requires a DF but my`'jsonResults'` is no longer a DataFrame now.

Comment: Instead of converting it to json, this might work if you pop the entries into an array column

Answer (score 0):

In order to put it in JSON array format I usually do the following:
df --> DataFrame containing the original data.

```
if df.count() > 0:
    # Build the json file
    data = list()
    for row in df.collect():
        data.append({"a": row['a'],
                     "b" : row['b']
                    })
```

I haven't use the Glue `write_dynamic_frame.from_options` in this case but I use `boto3` to save the file:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# Dump the json file to s3 bucket  
filename = '/{0}_batch_{1}.json'.format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, filename)
obj.put(Body=json.dumps(data))
```